# Strange behavior in AutoFitColumns using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I encountered a very strange behavior in EPPlus, especially Autofit.
The following code resizes columns 1 and 2:

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory");
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "foo";
worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "bar";
worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);
```

If I remove one of the two setters, it doesn't resize anything.

This behavior seems to be independent from the rest of the document: if one of the cells A1 or B1 is empty, AutoFitColumns doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm using version EPPlus 4.1.0.

Comment: Humm..I see it too.  Looks like a bug?